# Laravel authentication confusing

Tags: laravel, authentication, model

I'm beginner at Laravel.

I wanted to use:

```
Auth::login(users::find(1))
```

**Result:**
Type error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\users given

I **changed the model to extend Authenticatable instead of Model**.
Also I changed the Auth statement to:

```
Auth::login(users::where('id', 1))
```

**Result:**
Type error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must
>   implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable,
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given

I wonder if you would help me, 'Appreciation'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You, should implement Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable in users Model class to pass through  Auth::login

> Authenticate A User Instance
>
> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application,
>   you may call the login method with the user instance. The given object
>   must be an implementation of the
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract. Of course, the
>   App\User model included with Laravel already implements this
>   interface:
>
> Auth::login($user);

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

Or you can simply do this:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```